# Objective C char array mismatch

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, byte

I am having an issue getting the correct format of a char array in Objective C

*Correct sample:*

> unsigned char bytes[] = {2, 49, 53, 49, 3, 54};

When printing to the debug area I get this:

```
Printing description of bytes:
(unsigned char [6]) bytes = "\x02151\x0365"
```

*Incorrect sample:*

I then attempt to populate an unsigned char array with characters manually (via a for-loop that produces the below samples):

> unsigned char bb[64];

bb[0] = 2;

bb[1] = 49;

bb[2] = 52;

bb[3] = 49;

bb[4] = 3;

bb[5] = 54;

When printing to the debug area I get this:

```
Printing description of bb: (unsigned char [64]) bb = "\x02151\x036";
```

Also when expanding the array while debugging I can see xcode is telling me that the 'bytes' array has int values and the 'bb' array has characters such as '\x02' in it.

This is just a high level piece of code that does not do much yet, but I need to match the array named 'bytes' before being able to proceed.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: And what is *"wrong"* about that output? Check what characters 02, 49, 53 and so on refer to.

Comment: I think the last 5 in first top output is incorrect (should simply be removed) - or is that what you are actually asking about?

Comment: @JAS please show how you are printing/logging the data in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't:

- state what kind (local, instance, etc.) of variables `bytes` and `bb` are and that makes a difference;
- show your `for` loop; or
- state what you mean by "printing"

so this answer is going to be a **guess**!

Try the following code (it's a "complete" Cocoa app):

```
@implementation AppDelegate

unsigned char bytes[] = {2, 49, 53, 49, 3, 54};

char randomBytes[] = { 0x35, 0x0 };

unsigned char bb[64];

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
   for(int ix = 0; ix < 6; ix++) bb[ix] = bytes[ix];
   // breakpoint here
}

@end
```

Now in the debugger, *at least on my machine/compiler combination, this result is **not** guaranteed*:

```
(lldb) p bytes
(unsigned char [6]) $0 = "\x02151\x0365"
(lldb) p bb
(unsigned char [64]) $1 = "\x02151\x036"
```

I think this reproduces your result. So what is going on?

The variable `bytes` is an *array* but as it is characters the debugger is choosing to interpret it as a *C string* when displaying it - note the double quotes around the value and the `\x` hex escapes for non-printable characters.

A C string terminates on a null (zero) byte so when the debugger interprets your array as a C string it will display characters until it finds a null byte and stops. It just so happens that on your machine the two bytes following your `bytes` array have the values `0x35` and `0x0`; I have reproduced that here by adding the `randomBytes` array; and those values are the character `5` and the null byte so the debugger prints the `5`.

So why does `bb` only print 6 characters? Global variables are zero initialised, so `bb` has 64 null bytes before the `for` loop. After the loop the 7th of those null bytes acts as the EOS (end of string) marker and the print just shows the 6 characters you expect.

Finally why do I say the above results are **not** guaranteed? The memory layout order of global variables is not specified as part of the C Standard, which underlies Objective-C, so there is in fact no guarantee that the `randomBytes` array immediately follows the `bytes` array. If the global variable layout algorithm is different on your computer/compiler combination you may not get the same results. However the underlying cause of your issue is the same - the "printing" is running off the end of your `bytes` array.

HTH

Comment: A great answer that makes sense to me - thank you sir